# Passing Configurable Product ID to universal analytics on the success page

Tags: configurable-product, google-analytics

I'm using [Daniel Yovchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448733/daniel-yovchev)'s solution here to implement Universal Analytics:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229312/universal-analytics-could-not-track-transaction-in-magento?answertab=active#tab-top

The Current Code:

```
protected function _getOrdersTrackingCode()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds))
    ;
    $result = array("
        // Transaction code...
        ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
    ");

    foreach ($collection as $order) {
        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $address = $order->getBillingAddress();
        } else {
            $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        }

        $result[] = "
            ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                id:          '".$order->getIncrementId()."', // Transaction ID
                affiliation: '".$this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())."', // Affiliation or store name
                revenue:     '".$order->getBaseGrandTotal()."', // Grand Total
                shipping:    '".$order->getBaseShippingAmount()."', // Shipping cost
                tax:         '".$order->getBaseTaxAmount()."', // Tax

            });
        ";

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {

            $result[] = "
            ga('ecommerce:addItem', {

                id:       '".$order->getIncrementId()."', // Transaction ID.
                sku:      '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku())."', // SKU/code.
                name:     '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName())."', // Product name.
                category: '', // Category or variation. there is no 'category' defined for the order item
                price:    '".$item->getBasePrice()."', // Unit price.
                quantity: '".$item->getQtyOrdered()."' // Quantity.

            });
        ";

        }
        $result[] = "ga('ecommerce:send');";
    }
    return implode("\n", $result);
}
```

The problem I have is that this returns the simple sku, and I need it to return the configurable to be of any benefit to us.  How can I modify this:

```
           sku:      '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku())."', // SKU/code.
```

to serve this purpose?

Thanks ahead of time for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a configurable product you could do:

```
foreach($item->getChildrenItems() as $child) {
    sku:      '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($child->getSku())."', // SKU/code. 
}
```

Because there is only one child item, this produces one line. But if you have a group or bundle product, there might be more childs!